# Symfony 4 and Behat: how to inject the entity manager

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, behat

I've been using behat and symfony for quite a while. I have some contexts that use the entity manager to create some test data, but when I started using Symfony 4 I can not find a way to inject it to the context.

I think the closest I got was using ContextServiceExtension from FOB but I always get this error

> The service "mysite.context.catalog" has a dependency on a
>   non-existent service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager".

This is my services.xml for behat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services">
    <services>
        <service id="mysite.context.catalog" class="Shopery\MySite\Behat\CatalogContext">
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" />
            <tag name="fob.context_service" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

And this my behat.yml:

```
default:
  formatters:
    pretty:
      verbose: true
      paths: true
      snippets: true

  extensions:
    FriendsOfBehat\CrossContainerExtension: ~

    FriendsOfBehat\SymfonyExtension:
      env_file: .env_test
      kernel:
        bootstrap: ~
        class: 'Shopery\Ecommerce\Infrastructure\Symfony\Kernel'
        path: src/Infrastructure/Symfony/Kernel.php
        debug: true

    FriendsOfBehat\ContextServiceExtension:
       imports:
        - "tests/Behat/config/services.xml"

    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://ecommerce.wip/'
      sessions:
        default:
          goutte: ~

  gherkin:
    cache: ~

  suites:
    default:
      paths:
        - "%paths.base%/tests/functional"

      contexts:
        - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext

      contexts_services:
        - mysite.context.catalog
```

Comment: When you run bin/console debug:container  do you have this doctrine service here or not?

Comment: @Eakethet yes, absolutely, the service exists. I get the same error with any other service

Comment: and why is your service.yaml of type XML?

Comment: sorry, its services.xml

Comment: when you type bin/console debug:container doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager  is Public   Yes? Or is it as private?

Comment: they're public, i think the problem is bethat and symfony have different containers